# Maven child module not found when building

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to learn how maven multi-project builds work. I have a very simple setup right now, a top level POM that defines 1 subproject, the web application, and a web project that has a pretty basic pom file. From the parent level directory, when i try to run 'mvn clean install' i get the following error:

```
Child module /home/jeb/Desktop/payroll/payroll-web> of /home/jeb/Desktop/payroll/pom.xml does not exist
```

Here is the parent pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>payroll</groupId>
    <artifactId>payroll-top</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>payroll-web></module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

And here is the subproject (web app) pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>payroll-web</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>payroll</groupId>
        <artifactId>payroll-top</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>payroll</groupId>
    <artifactId>payroll-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>payrollwebapp</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm not sure what I am missing to get the project to build, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a trailing ">" at the end of the module name.

```
    <module>payroll-web></module>
```

Comment: that worked, running into another issue:  Non-resolvable parent POM for payroll:payroll-web:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact payroll:payroll-top:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM I guess it can't find the parent pom?

Comment: I think you have the versions mismatched. 1.0-SNAPSHOT in your parent pom and 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in the parent ref in the child pom.

Answer (score 1):

```
`<parent>
    <groupId>payroll</groupId>
    <artifactId>payroll-top</artifactId>
    <version>*0.0.1-SNAPSHOT*</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>`
```

Correct the parent version to 1.0